# laravel mail sending dynamic subject

Tags: laravel

i can send mail with laravel as below, but what i want is this; I want to make the subject part dynamic, how can I achieve this?

```
$sendAdmin['sendAdmin'] = $data;
        Mail::to('hello@word.com')->send(new \App\Mail\ContactMail($sendAdmin));
```

```
class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $details = [];

    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->subject('Hello Mail')->view('email.contactform');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the subject comes from your `$details` array, it's pretty simple:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject($this->details['subject'])->view('email.contactform');
}
```